# Подключение к Firebird на php

Tags: php, firebird

Проблема с подключением из php к firebird-базе. Код для подключения:

```
$database   = "192.168.1.34:C:/db.gdb";

$user       = "SYSDBA";

$password   = "masterkey";

$db = ibase_connect($database, $user, $password);
```

Однако при его выполнении сервер выдаёт ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ibase_connect()
```

Но при этом нужные расширения подключены - php_interbase и php_pdo_firebird. В чём ещё может быть дело?

Comment: А вы уверены, что они подключены? в php_info() проверяли?

Comment: Да, это первым делом проверил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, вопрос решился. Нужно было взять клиентскую библиотеку gds32.dll и скопировать её в директорию апача. Причём файл нужно брать строго тот же, что используется в базе данных Firebird, иначе не сработает.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = @ibase_connect($database, $user, $password);
```

так вообще-то нужно. Мог даже перевести ошибку и понять: "Вызов к неопределенной функции".

Comment: Я перевёл и про "вызов неопределённой функции" понял. Вопрос-то не в этом. Вопрос в том, почему она неопределённая, если все нужные библиотеки подключены?