# Как можно вытащить данные с базы gdb firebird

Tags: php, база-данных, firebird

Есть база на хостинге test.gdb сделана firebird, как я могу ее подключить к сайту через PHP?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929822/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-gdb-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-php?noredirect=1#comment1539469_929822).

Comment: Базы подключаются 1) через нейтивный драйвер для среды (пхп). 2)через извесный интерфейс (ODBC, OLEDB, JDBC) при наличии всех компонентов драйвера базы. Информации на эту тему - полно. Если не понятно с чего начать - откройте базу сначала IBExpert утилитой. Можно почитать в сети как где и что, а уже когда извесна версия драйвера и т п - уже искать как это делать средствами php. Для gdb есть одна загвоздка - нужно версию БД знать. Если не извесна версия бд - то два пути 1) тупо пробовать все версии драйвера (1.5 2.0 2.5...). 2) по сигнатуре файла смотреть версию.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня мак. Вся информация по базе есть, надо пример подключения

Comment: @Akina автор удалил вопрос))) куда идет ссылка - ну... ничего не извесно, что за база, какой версии  - поэтому вопрос всёравно **закроется** или как **слишком общий** скорее всего.

Comment: Примеров подключения в сети валом. Вот первый с поиска на SO http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14456/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-firebird-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php вот целый список всячины с ответами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+firebird